# Google Web Fonts and woff

Tags: font-face

Google offers only woff version of their fonts, and it renders without any problems on iOS devices.
But If same Google code with own woff font used, it stops working.

Here the Google code with offline use and it works both on desktop & mobile,

```
<style type="text/css">
@font-face {
font-family: 'Keania One';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
src: local('Keania One'), url(Xs0xx5kHUREmTXw6nnDuChsxEYwM7FgeyaSgU71cLG0.woff) format('woff');
}
body {
font-family: Keania One;
font-size: 150px;
}
</style>
```

SVG don't work even If have the the correct ID and so on, is this a font issue? or something I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

The Google Webfont code, like this, looks like a link to a static CSS-file.

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gabriela'
 rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

However, it's not. It's a script detecting your OS and browser, generating proper font-face CSS depending on what your browser supports. It's clever as it only loads the the supported file.

Your code should work though, at least where WOFF-files are supported. One thing though, You need to write the body font-family like this:

```
font-family: 'Keania One';
```

Comment: Well I downloaded the woff font from Google and used it locally, My ipad renders it without any problem, Safari renders that woff font as it should. But if I use another woff font or SVG ipad can't render them. I'm sure that something is wrong with the font I'm trying to use, but its a standard font that works fine on desktop, what could be missing from my font that makes it unusable on iPad? Are there any specific requirements for a woff font to work on mobile devices?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still new with all this but I hope this can help a little bit. If you could download the font you want to use you can go to [Fontsquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) they offer a free service for converting your own fonts you have to web fonts and you can download the web kit. So maybe if you make your own web font kit and use that instead somehow it may fix it. Hopefully this helps, my apologies if it doesn't.

Comment: I have tried every possible generator out there, none of them works the same as Googles, yet Googles code includes only ony font format and not 3 or 4. There must be a secret with Googles woff. Hope experts can help us.

Comment: yea hopefully, sorry I couldnt be of more help.